# Transform animation's breaks in Safari only

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have some CSS transforms that happen on a click event and on hover. The transforms work fine in Chrome and Firefox, but not Safari. In Safari the transforms reset the border radius and the opacity before starting.

Codepen of the elements: https://codepen.io/IamJoshing/pen/yqxaYa

I am using bootstrap 4 and here is the code I added:

```
.testimonials .testimonial-item > img{
    border-radius: 30px;
    opacity: .5;
    padding: 15px;
}
.testimonials .testimonial-item.active > img{
    animation: SHWimg 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}
@keyframes SHWimg {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: -webkit-scale(1);
        -moz-transform:scale(1);
        -o-transform:scale(1);
        transform:scale(1);     
        border-radius: 30px;
        padding: 15px;
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: -webkit-scale(1);
        -moz-transform:scale(1);
        -o-transform:scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
        border-radius: 20px;
        padding: 0px;

    }
}
.testimonials .testimonial-item.active > img{
    border-radius: 20px;
    opacity: 1;
    padding: 0;
}
.testimonials .testimonial-item > img:hover {
    border-radius: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1.5s ease;
    -o-transition: opacity 1.5s ease;
    transition: opacity 1.5s ease;
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: please post your html as well. This gives us very little to work off. Also try and recreate this in a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.com) or [codepen](http://www.codepen.io) to give us something to go off.

Comment: Just add a link to Codepen https://codepen.io/IamJoshing/pen/yqxaYa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main issue is related to the `padding` + `border-radius` combination.

See the examples below, although the 2nd image has exactly the same border radius as the 1st one, but in fact it doesn't show any due to the padding, and the 3rd one explains why that happens.

```css
img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.padding {
  padding: 30px;
}

.border {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placekitten.com/g/90/90">
<img src="http://placekitten.com/g/90/90" class="padding">
<img src="http://placekitten.com/g/90/90" class="padding border">
```

As a workaround for your case, I would suggest to use `transform: scale()` instead of `padding` to control the image size. Set `transform: scale(0.75)` initially, then change it to `transform: scale(1)` in the animation.

**[Updated Pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/djqpVw?editors=1100)**

Comment: Awesome! I removed the padding and border radius from the keyframe and just used scale. Works!... probably how it should have in the first place. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
You can add Prefix for safari
@-webkit-keyframes SHWimg {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: -webkit-scale(1);
        -moz-transform:scale(1);
        -o-transform:scale(1);
        transform:scale(1);     
        border-radius: 30px;
        padding: 15px;
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: -webkit-scale(1);
        -moz-transform:scale(1);
        -o-transform:scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
        border-radius: 20px;
        padding: 0px;

    }
}
```